# Getting domain names registered since TIMESTAMP

Tags: dns

Is there a single, or small group of, root servers I can send a query along the lines of,

```
return domain names created after TIMESTAMP
```

If so, how would I ask for it ?
I came across something called "zone-transfer" but it looks unreliable and likely to have me running into permission problems.

// Edit -- I want to get the list of .COM domains created since $TIMESTAMP. I'm not asking about programming issues - parsing the file and so on - just about where to find the data.

Comment: You should fix the question because you asked first about root servers then, in a comment to an answer, you talk about .COM servers.

Comment: That's my problem though, I really don't know what question to ask, or where to ask it. :)

Comment: Let me suggest (and see if my crystal ball works fine) "I want to get the list of .COM domains created since $TIMESTAMP. I'm not asking about programming issues - parsing the file and so on - just about where to find the data." And the answer is "Not gratis, you have to pay (and, for the whole .COM, not just for one registrar, you have to find where to ask because it is far from obvious on Verisign's Web site)."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several root name servers accept zone transfers (for instance `f.root-servers.net`). But you do not need it, the entire zone file is distributed [with FTP](ftp://rs.internic.net/domain/named.root).

It does not include an history. You have to parse it and manage the history yourself. See for instance [my talk at ICANN](http://www.icann.org/en/meetings/saopaulo/presentation-cntr-monitoring-iana-07dec06.pdf).

The last domains created in the root name servers were RS (Serbia) and ME (Montenegro) in september 2007.

Comment: Is there a way I can get domain names such as "new-domain.com" along with their date of creation using these ? Parsing/retrieval is not a problem I'll take any format I can get my hands on as long as it's current, I just need to know where I can get the information from. :)

Comment: Not at the root name servers. new-domain.com is hosted on the .COM name servers which do not allow zone transfers. The entire zone, as a file, is only distributed for a fee. See http://www.icann.org/en/registrars/ra-agreement-17may01.htm, section 3.3.6